# Garageband workaround: Tempo change post-recording?

Tags: audio, music, garageband

Is there a way to change the master tempo in Garageband *after* you've already recorded some audio tracks?

Use case:

1. Create analog audio tracks (e.g. record guitar, voice, etc.)
2. Manually figure out the tempo of the recorded audio
3. Set the master tempo to this value
4. Add a drummer track which plays at this tempo

Any time you change the master tempo, it re-times *all* the tracks, which is exactly NOT what I want it to do.  I want it to not touch my analog audio tracks, and just add a drum track at the tempo I specify.

I realize Garageband isn't really intended for use as a DAW, but this seems like such a simple -- and common -- use case.  Yes, I know I could create the drum track first and pay along with it;  but that's not the question.

Any ideas?

Comment: Great question. I also felt like this was a dead obvious use case, and I can't believe that there's no answer yet. Could it be it's not possible?

Comment: Answered my own question: it's just the ol' "you have to pay for that feature" trick.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out there's a simple answer:  all this is supported in Logic.  Garageband and Logic are the same piece of software;  Garageband is the limited version.

I upgraded to Logic after being frustrated with this (and many other limitations).  It was well worth it.